# Google Maps API - get fuel consumption

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm building a Google Maps API's based web page, letting the user asking for a travel, let's say from a point A to a point B.
I'm now able to show the directions, but...I'm not able to find a way to show the fuel consumption, like Google maps do...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is part of the maps API, but rather a feature on maps.google.com
You could get the distance though and then calculate the fuel-consumption yourself based on some factor.